# How does a backend node API prevent bad actors from abusing the API or request overload?

Tags: reactjs, node.js

I have a node APP that is meant to handle requests from my front end react APP, which will have millions of users.

How do I prevent request overload from either a genuine user or bad actors trying to attack my APP?

Comment: use an api-gateway to handle routing and rate limiting